# Error when trying to do a redirect using the header() method

Tags: php, html, sql, codeigniter, redirect

I'm using this code to redirect but it shows error

```html
<?php
header(Location: . site_url("./admin/dashboard"));
die();
```

I know its a small problem. Still if anyone can help I will be grateful

Comment: "but it shows error"  _what error_???

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':'

Comment: How can you work with an advanced framewok like CI, without even knowing PHP syntax basics?

Comment: You can use codeigniter `redirect(base_url('admin/dashboard));` You need to load the url helper https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#redirect

Answer (score 2):

You should add quotes to your string.

```
<?php
header('Location:' . site_url("./admin/dashboard"));
die();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this, it's a good idea to put the full address to redirect but can do this with the relative address.

**Note**: you must put Location: in quite.

```
<?php
header("Location: ". site_url("./admin/dashboard")); /* Redirect browser */

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```